# How to use Multipie view in RecycerView on Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want load data from server and show it into `Recyclerview` but I should show `RecyclerView` such as this design : 
[Click link to see image](http://uupload.ir/files/z88b_mzg8j.jpg)

**My json :**

```
{
    "android": [{
        "ver": "1.5",
        "name": "Cupcake",
        "api": "API level 3"
    }, {
        "ver": "1.6",
        "name": "Donut",
        "api": "API level 4"
    }, {
        "ver": "2.0 - 2.1",
        "name": "Eclair",
        "api": "API level 5 - 7"
    }, {
        "ver": "2.2",
        "name": "Froyo",
        "api": "API level 8"
    }, {
        "ver": "2.3",
        "name": "Gingerbread",
        "api": "API level 9 - 10"
    }, {
        "ver": "3.0 - 3.2",
        "name": "Honeycomb",
        "api": "API level 11 - 13"
    }, {
        "ver": "4.0",
        "name": "Ice Cream Sandwich",
        "api": "API level 14 - 15"
    }, {
        "ver": "4.1 - 4.3",
        "name": "JellyBean",
        "api": "API level 16 - 18"
    }, {
        "ver": "4.4",
        "name": "KitKat",
        "api": "API level 19"
    }, {
        "ver": "5.0 - 5.1",
        "name": "Lollipop",
        "api": "API level 21 - 22"
    }, {
        "ver": "6.0",
        "name": "Marshmallow",
        "api": "API level 23"
    }, {
        "ver": "7.0 - 7.1",
        "name": "Nougat",
        "api": "API level 24 - 25"
    }]
}
```

I want show fist data into big layout and when get new data from server, show previous in small layout and show new data into big layout.

I know I want use **Multipiew** view in `recyclerview`, but how??!

I am amateur and I really nned this, please help me

Comment: You would get the answer with a basic query of google. like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `LayoutManager` to achieve what you want.

For your case, you may want to use a `GridLayoutManager`, because it allows yo define a `span size` for each item.

The `span` for an item in a `GridLayoutManager` is the amount of `GridLayoutManager.span` this item will take.

For example, if your `GridLayoutManager` has a span of **2**, your first item (the one full width) will have a `span` of **2**, and the next ones will have a `span` of **1**.

**Edit** :

Assuming you declared `layoutManager` and `recyclerView` fields previously in your code, here is the few lines that should do what you want :

```
layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2)  {
    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return false;
    }
};

/**
* overriding getSpanSize allows to have different number of items per rows
* this is useful since you want one item full width on first line and 2 items on other lines and take
* more size than other items.
* @param position the position of the {@link RecyclerView} item in the list of items
* @return the span size
*/
layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        // if position is 0, i.e., first item of recycler, it has span of 2. 
        // Else, it has span of 1 (1/2 of the total GridLayoutManager span)
        return (position == 0) ? 2 : 1;
    }
});

// then tell the recyclerview to display itself using its layout manager
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept this ansxer so further users can quickly know that my answer is a solution to this problem. Also, please read the FAQ before you post, because your question doesn't respect StackOverflow standards.

Comment: Thanks man, but not found `setSpanSizeLookup` method. can you send me this method codes? please